# Assembly 'System.Memory' not found when using Entity.FrameworkCore.Sqlite in Xamarin project

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get a project based on Xamarin with a .Net standard project and entity framework core to work, but I cannot resolve the following error:

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   Could not load assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Perhaps it doesn't
>   exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name: 'System.Memory.dll' 
>   at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver, ICollection`1 assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly,
>   Boolean topLevel)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver
>   resolver)

For the reference management I am using the nuget package manager in VS2017 and the project is setup to use the packages.config as suggested [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/8922#issuecomment-345375260).

The nuget package System.Memory is installed for the Android project, so I'm a bit clueless what could cause the error. Only the version is different, installed is version 4.5.0 and according to the error message it's checking for 4.0.1.0, yet this version does not exist for System.Memory.

Anyone can relate to this error or provide any hints / help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update of VS2017 to version 15.7.3 solved the problem

Comment: Just curious: Are you able to build with "Sdk Assemblies Only" linking enabled?